# What line should I remove from this Google maps script

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-apps-script

I got a question regarding this code for googlemaps for my website. My website is pretty big (350 pages) and I am using a website that saves me a lot of time by quickly creating code without me manually writing it.

However this website injects some links in their code for advertisement and backlinks (https://www.acadoo.de/de-ghostwriter-bachelorarbeit.html'>Ghostwriter Bachelorarbeit).

What should I remove from this snippet to get rid of it without making whole code non workable? This is my first question on this website, Im sorry if this is a common question and I didnt find an answer.

```html
<script src='https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&key=AIzaSyDvV9lr4YTbExSlhYI2e26aTEaoY2peUwE'></script>
<div style='overflow:hidden;height:280px;width:1382px;'>
  <div id='gmap_canvas' style='height:280px;width:1382px;'></div>
  <style>
    #gmap_canvas img {
      max-width: none!important;
      background: none!important
    }
  </style>
</div> <a href='https://www.acadoo.de/de-ghostwriter-bachelorarbeit.html'>Ghostwriter Bachelorarbeit</a>
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://embedmaps.com/google-maps-authorization/script.js?id=274228f8880db3e0b587b128af8f2a5a49d26d62'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
  function init_map() {
    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 14,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(47.4464864, 9.526921600000037),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('gmap_canvas'), myOptions);
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(47.4464864, 9.526921600000037)
    });
    infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: '<strong>Klinik Am Rosenberg</strong><br>Hasenbühlstrasse 11<br>9410 Heiden<br>'
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
  }
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init_map);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need to remove both of these lines:

```
<a href='https://www.acadoo.de/de-ghostwriter-bachelorarbeit.html'>Ghostwriter Bachelorarbeit</a>
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://embedmaps.com/google-maps-authorization/script.js?id=274228f8880db3e0b587b128af8f2a5a49d26d62'></script>
```

**working code snippet:**

```html
<script src='https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&key=AIzaSyDvV9lr4YTbExSlhYI2e26aTEaoY2peUwE'></script>
<div style='overflow:hidden;height:280px;width:1382px;'>
  <div id='gmap_canvas' style='height:280px;width:1382px;'></div>
  <style>
    #gmap_canvas img {
      max-width: none!important;
      background: none!important
    }
  </style>
</div>
<script type='text/javascript'>
  function init_map() {
    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 14,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(47.4464864, 9.526921600000037),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('gmap_canvas'), myOptions);
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(47.4464864, 9.526921600000037)
    });
    infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: '<strong>Klinik Am Rosenberg</strong><br>Hasenbühlstrasse 11<br>9410 Heiden<br>'
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
  }
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init_map);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, isn't the only thing you want to remain the link?

```
 <a href='https://www.acadoo.de/de-ghostwriter-bachelorarbeit.html'>Ghostwriter Bachelorarbeit</a>
```

From the snippet, the rest appears to setup to display the maps (reference the API (script tag), setup the 'canvas' (div tag) and then authorize/invoke (last two script tags).

Note the first line might be used on other pages as well if you have multiple references (othwerwise all should be able to be removed I would expect):

Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: What I want is to remove this line that you highlighted from the code. However if I remove it, the snippet stops working, because I am doing something wrong.

I will rephrase the question. How can I remove the line you highlighted without crashing the code.